# Cant Jump In Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qQu4o2HQ8Q&t=177s) how to make a First Person Movement Script, but sometimes it jumps sometimes dont i dont know whats happening. I really need help im new in this world and im trying to study but its a little bit confusing and i really appreciate the help guys

```
public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed = 1f;
    public float jumpPower = 10f;

    public float gravityFactor = -9.81f;
    public float currentVelY = 0;

    public bool isSprinting = false;
    public float sprintingMultiplier;

    public bool isCrouching = false;
    public float crouchingMulitplier;

    public CharacterController controller;
    public float standingHeight = 1.8f;
    public float crouchingHeight = 1.25f;

    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public Transform groundDetectionTransform;


    public bool isGrounded;

    public void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    public void CheckIsGrounded()
    {
        Collider[] cols = Physics.OverlapSphere(groundDetectionTransform.position, 0.05f, groundMask);

        if (cols.Length > 0)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float inputY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        CheckIsGrounded();

        if (isGrounded == false)
        {
            currentVelY += gravityFactor * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            currentVelY = -2f;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && isGrounded == true)
        {
            currentVelY = jumpPower;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            isCrouching = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isCrouching = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && isCrouching == false)
        {
            isSprinting = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSprinting = false;
        }

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3();

        movement = inputX * transform.right + inputY * transform.forward;

        if (isCrouching == true)
        {
            controller.height = crouchingHeight;
            movement *= crouchingMulitplier;
        }
        else
        {
            controller.height = standingHeight;
        }

        if (isSprinting == true)
        {
            movement *= sprintingMultiplier;
        }

        controller.Move(movement * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        controller.Move(new Vector3(0,currentVelY * Time.deltaTime,0));
    }
}
```

If you can help me i really appreciate it

Comment: the code seems correct, please post some images of your scene to help understanding the problem. If you could share all your project it will be better to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple, you never set the `isGrounded` variable to `true` therefore you can't jump.

My personal advice, make sure you watched the tutorial to the end and if you did watch some better tutorials.